# import cv2 in Sagemaker Studio jupyter notebook throws ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have run `pip install opencv-python` however when I do `import cv2` I get this error `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I tried the steps described here too https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2):

use this from sagars answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710022/import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-obj)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: How will this work if you don't have root access to the host where **Jupyter** runs on?

Comment: !pip install opencv-python-headless 
instead of !pip install opencv-python should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If your environment does not allow you to sudo, you can instead of the standard opencv-python package, get the headless version of it

```
!pip install opencv-python-headless
```

which brings its binaries with it