# Unable to run docker image due to libGl error

Tags: python-3.x, docker, opencv, matplotlib, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install opencv-python==4.3.0.38
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12
Werkzeug==0.16.1
boto3==1.14.40
torch
torchvision==0.7.0
numpy==1.15.4
sklearn==0.0
scipy==1.2.1
scikit-image==0.14.2
pandas==0.24.2
```

The docker build succeeds but the docker run fails with the error

```
INFO:matplotlib.font_manager:Generating new fontManager, this may take some time...
PyTorch Version:  1.6.0
Torchvision Version:  0.7.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pipeline_prediction.pipeline import ml_pipeline 
  File "/app/pipeline_prediction/pipeline.py", line 3, in <module>
    from segmentation_color import get_swatch_color_from_segmentation
  File "pipeline_prediction/segmentation_color.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked at answer [import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710022/import-matplotlib-pyplot-as-plt-importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-obj)  relating to it and replaced

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

with

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

but it is not working for me. Also looked at [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo) but I do not have Ubuntu as base image so this installation would not work for me as listed in the answer.

Let me know a way to make this work.

Comment: For the [standard Docker Hub Python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), the `python:<version>` images are Debian-based and the `apt-get install` from the linked question should work.  You'd need to explicitly select a `python:<version>-alpine` image.

Comment: /bin/sh: apt-get: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install 'ffmpeg'    'libsm6'    'libxext6'  -y' returned a non-zero code: 127 is what i get when i use alpine based image or not

Comment: The command '/bin/sh -c apt install libgl1-mesa-glx' returned a non-zero code: 1 same with other alternative as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to make the docker container run by making following changes to the dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y
RUN apt-get install 'ffmpeg'\
    'libsm6'\
    'libxext6'  -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install opencv-python==4.3.0.38
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

The lines required for resolving the libGl error

```
RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx -y
RUN apt-get install 'ffmpeg'\
    'libsm6'\
    'libxext6'  -y
```

were not able to run without updating the ubuntu environment. Moreover creating the docker image as noninteractive helped to skip any interactive command line inputs