# pyinstaller + docker + openCV

Tags: python, docker, opencv, pyinstaller

I am trying to use pyinstaller to package a simple python script that imports cv2 module and all this should be done inside a docker container (this is part of a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline).

I think I am doing this right in the right order, i.e.

- start a docker python image,
- then I can run `apt-get install -y python3-opencv`
- `pip install opencv-python`
- `pip install pyinstaller`
- `pyinstaller -F sample.py`

sample.py can be

```
import cv2
print("hello")
```

When I run the resulting executable I get the error: `ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've tried locating this library and adding to --paths option for pyinstaller but iwht no luck. Any help is appreciated

Comment: use a headless variant of the opencv-python package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run docker image due to libGl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889102/unable-to-run-docker-image-due-to-libgl-error)

Comment: All the provided solutions didn't work for me... but in the end I didn't use a docker image, and I am using a virtual environment and that solved my issue. I'll leave this uestion open as maybe in the future someone finds a solution to this